# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^q+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can anyone give a me a hint on how to check if this series is convergent or not?
 $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^{q}+1} $$

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the *limit comparison test* with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ for various values of $p$.

Comment: Indeed. Good rule of thumb: Any positive power of $n$ trumps $\ln n$.

Comment: ok, so if p>1 it is convergent and for p<1 is divergent. But then I should say that 1/n^p is a majorant/minorant?

Comment: I was wrong, that's not the case for majorant or minorant. I just say that the two series have a similar behavior.

Comment: The nice thing about the limit comparison test as opposed to the comparison test is that only the limit behavior of the ratio is needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Comparison test**
We have that $\log n < n$. If $q > 2$ then

$\frac{\log n}{n^q + 1} < \frac{n}{n^q +1} = \frac{1}{n^{q-1} + \frac{1}{n}}< \frac{1}{n^{q-1}}$, then
since for $q> 2$ the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{q-1}}$ converges, then by comparison theorem so is $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\log n }{n^q + 1}$.

**Comparison test and Limit comparison test**
Now let $q \in (0, 1]$
for $n \geq 3$
$\frac{1}{n^q+1}<\frac{\log{n}}{n^q+1}$
and the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^q+1}$ is divergent due to limit comparison test with the sum $\sum \frac{1}{n^q}$. Indeed $\frac{n^q+1}{n^q} \to 1$. Hence,
$\sum \frac{\log n }{n^q+1}$ is divergent when $q \in (0, 1]$.

The case which I'm leaving for you is when $q \in (1, 2]$.